# Function not working on jQuery 1.6.x (but worked on 1.5.x)

Tags: jquery, attr, jquery-1.6

This works in 1.5.2, but doesn't on 1.6.2. The button won't get 'enabled'. I think it has to be with the .attr

How could i fix this?

```
function checkMessageForm() {
    var message_chars = $("#form_dm_text").val().length;
    console.log(message_chars);
    if (message_chars > 0 && message_chars < 14001) $("#form_dm_submit").attr("disabled", "");
    else
    $("#form_dm_submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should delete the `disabled` attribute:

```
$("#form_dm_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
```

You can see the effect of `removeAttr('disabled')` versus `attr('disabled', '')` here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JMvKr/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.attr("disabled", "")`, try `.removeAttr("disabled")` ?

Comment: oops - my answer is a dupe :)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the [.prop(propertyName, value)](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) solution. Mostly it is just another option that wasn't mentioned here.

```
function checkMessageForm() {
    var message_chars = $("#form_dm_text").val().length;
    console.log(message_chars);
    var disable = message_chars > 0 && message_chars < 14001;
    $("#form_dm_submit").prop("disabled", disable);
}
```

`attr()` also accepts a true and false as the value to enable/disable.